# Altering django model data based on link selected in prior view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I would like the link that a user clicks on to instantiate a model differently on a subsequent view.

I have a page ‘tools.html’ that is a templateView:

urls.py

```
    path(
        "tools/",
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pages/tools.html"),
        name="tools",
    )
```

tools.html has two links (AP and AD) on it  - both should go to the same template ’se_balance.html’ a page where users complete a form.

The view for se_balance.html is:

```
class CaseView(TemplateView):
    model = Case
    template_name = "../templates/se_balance.html"
    
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('getting')
        case_form = CaseForm
        sideeffect_formset = SideeffectFormSet(queryset=SideEffect.objects.none())

        return self.render_to_response(
            { "case_form": case_form,
              "sideeffect_formset": sideeffect_formset,
              "sideeffect_formsethelper": SideEffectFormSetSetHelper,
            }
        )

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CaseForm(data=self.request.POST)
        med_formset = MedFormSet(data=self.request.POST)
        sideeffect_formset = SideeffectFormSet(data=self.request.POST)
        sevseff_formset = SevseffFormSet(data=self.request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            case_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                case_instance.user = self.request.user
            case_instance.save()
        if sideeffect_formset.is_valid():
            sideeffect_name = sideeffect_formset.save(commit=False)
            for sideeffect in sideeffect_name:
                sideeffect.case = case_instance
                sideeffect.save()

            return redirect(
                reverse(
                    "results",
                    kwargs={"case_id": case_instance.case_id},
                )
            )
```

The ‘Case ‘ model is as follows:

```
class Case(TimeStampedModel):
    # get a unique id for each patient - could perhaps use this as slug if needed
    case_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False
    )
    # Remove blank=True if we want to make login compulsory
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    P_CHOICES = [(‘AD’, ‘AD’), 
                 (‘AP’, ‘AP’),]
```

Depending on the link that was clicked at tools.html I would like the model instantiated differently (i.e.e with P_CHOICEs as Either ‘AD’ or ‘AP’ but I am not sure of the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In both of the links in `tools.html` you can append a query param like `p` which you can then get in `CaseView`. For example:

```html
<a href="/link-to/se-balance?p=AP">AP</a>
<a href="/link-to/se-balance?p=AD"> AD </a>
```

You can extend this further by sending `P_CHOICES` into the template context of `tools.html` which would roughly look like this:

```html
{% for choice_value, choice_label in P_CHOICES %}
    <a href="/link-to/se-balance?p={{ choice_value }}">{{ choice_label }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Update 1:

You can get the URL query parameters via `self.request.GET` and initiate the form with its value.

```py
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('getting')
        print(self.request.GET)
        p = self.request.GET.get("p", None)
        # Change the name p_field accordingly
        case_form = CaseForm(initial={'p_field': p}) if p else CaseForm
```

Comment: Many thanks @thespiderdev please apologies for my ignorance but please could you expand on how I would alter the CaseView code (i have edited my question to show the full code for the view above)

Comment: @RobMcC No worries, you don't have to apologize. I updated my answer. I hope that would help. Let me know if you are able to solve it.

Comment: You can check this doc here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

Comment: thanks again @thespiderdev - I'm getting there. The issue now is that when I post I get the error "local variable 'case_instance' referenced before assignment" I think this is because the form is not valid.

Comment: Just to add for further info, the issue is I dont actually want case_form to be displayed to the user (if I do display it in the html things do work, but I dont want to have to display it)